# How to obtain the limit of $xy\log(x^2+y^2)$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ without using polar coordinates or L'Hôpital?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\ {xy\log(x^2+y^2)}$

I tried this:

$$xy\log(x^2+y^2)=xy\log(x^2)+xy\log(1+y^2/x^2)$$

$|xy\log(x^2)|=2|x||y||\log|x||$ (because I use $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$) $\le 2|x||y|||x|-1|$ and taking the limit, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\ {xy\log(x^2)}=0$.

Since the other member has two variables in the argument of $\log$, I don't know how to continue. I know the limit of this function is zero because proceeding with other methods I've seen the limit is zero.

Comment: Can you use $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \varepsilon\cdot \log \varepsilon = 0\,?$$ (in that case, use $2\lvert xy\rvert \leqslant x^2 + y^2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $|xy|\leq (x^2+y^2)/2$  (expand $(|x|-|y|)^2\geq 0$) and $$\lim_{t\to 0^+} t\cdot \log t =\lim_{s\to +\infty} \frac{-s}{e^{s}}=0
\quad\mbox{(where $s=-\log t$)}.$$