# Want to prove that: $\lim_{(x,y)\to\ (0,0)}xy\log(x^2+y^2)=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to see that the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to\ (0,0)}xy\log(x^2+y^2)=0$$
So my idea is to bound:
$$0\leq|xy\log(x^2+y^2)|$$ by something that tends to zero when $x,y\to(0,0)$, but I'm stuck with:
$$0\leq|xy\log(x^2+y^2)|\leq|(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)|$$ 
Since I don't know what to do with $\log(x^2+y^2)$.

Note: Working with real variables.

Comment: You may simply switch to polar coordinated and notice that $\sin\theta\cos\theta$ is bounded while $\lim_{\rho\to 0^+}\rho^2\log(\rho^2)=0$.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1914145/42969.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:
$$\log(x^2+y^2)\le2\max\{\log|x-y|,\log|x+y|\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write your term in the form
$$\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\times(x^2+y^2)\ln(x^2+y^2)$$ Now use that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+ }x\ln(x)=...$$=

Answer (score 0):

Let's transform $f(x,y) = xy\log(x^2+y^2)$ into a more useful form: Let
$$
x = r \cos \theta\\ y = r\sin \theta \\ f(x,y) = r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta \log(r^2) = r^2\cos (2\theta)\log r
$$

$\cos(2\theta)$ is bounded in absolute value being $\leq 1$ so 
$$
|f(x,y)| = |f(r,\theta)| \leq r^2\log r
$$
This holds for all $x$ and $y$.  Therefore, if 
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} r^2\log r = 0
$$
then 
$$
\lim_{x,y\to 0} f(x,y) = 0
$$
But writing $r^2 \log r = \frac{\log r}{r^{-2}}$ and appying L'Hopital's rule we see that limit is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can say when x and y, both goes to zero or very near to 0 then X is approximately equal to y.
So replace y with x then take limit as x tends to 0

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$xy\log(x^2+y^2)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\cdot (x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2) \to 0$$

indeed we can se for example by polar coordinates that

- $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=\sin \theta\cos \theta$

is bounded and since $t=x^2+y^2 \to 0$

- $(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2) =t \log t\to 0$